# c++ (u256)*(h256 const*)(char*[] + int) cast rewriting to java

Tags: java, c++, casting

i need to to rewrite some code from c++ to java and i've got into trouble with such c++ code:

```
using u256 = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::unsigned_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void>>;
using h256 = FixedHash<32>;
using bytes = std::vector<byte>;

uint32_t offset = ...;
bytes m_data = ...;
u256 result;
result = (u256)*(h256 const*)(m_data.data() + (size_t)offset);
```

I have no idea what's going on and how do i rewrite it in java code.
I've understood that firstly we made and offset and now pointing at some element of m_data array, then cast in to array of h256 type (i've watched debug and this cast made the following: we get data from 0 to offset from m_data and then cast to 32 size array with leading zero's)
And then we get a first value (im not sure about it) of this array and cast to u256? But the first value after (h256 const*) cast is zero but anyway the resulting value is not a zero.
Do u have any ideas?

Comment: What is `h256 `? What is `bytes`? What is `u256`?

Comment: Forget to notice that bytes is  std::vector<byte>

Comment: The address from `m_data.data() + (size_t)offset` is cast to a pointer-to-`h256`, dereferenced, the result of which is then cast to `u256`. That's what it does.

Comment: using h256 = FixedHash<32>
using u256 = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::unsigned_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void>>;

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and put all clarifications _there_.

Comment: Typically, when one needs to translate from one language to another, one doesn't convert between languages line-by-line. One should understand what does the code do, and re-write the overall behavior in a different language.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a u256 is, and the question miss the typedef, but this is the typical way in C to get a scalar type (int16_t, int32_t, int64_t, double....) from a buffer in memory.

Essentially the use of the syntax:

```
type t = (type)*(const type *)(buffer + offset)
```

... let you obtain an object of a specific type from a byte array starting from a particular index.

It's not very safe, but it blazing fast when converted to assembly!

*NOTE*: the pointer math depends from the declaration of "buffer", if it's int8_t * for instance buffer will be get from the "offset"-nth byte, if it's int32_t * it will be used from the "offset * 4"-nth byte.